# gridview is not showing Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

i am creating a website and creating two types of login 
1) admin
2) Zonal Partner Manager
when i logged in as admin my gridview of data is showing but when i logged in as ZPM gridview is not apearing

my aspx code

```
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div id="grd" style="height: 470px; width: 1623px; overflow: auto;">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="11pt"
        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
        CssClass="Grid" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AssignDate">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnnewRecord" runat="server" OnClick="NewRecord" Text="+" ToolTip="ADD New Record" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="AssignDate" Text="Assign Date" ToolTip="Assign Date For This Record" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"
                SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Zone" HeaderText="Zone" SortExpression="Zone" HeaderStyle-Width="80px"
                ItemStyle-Width="80px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VenueName" HeaderText="VenueName" SortExpression="VenueName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Venue" HeaderText="Venue" SortExpression="Venue" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VenueEmail" HeaderText="VenueEmail" SortExpression="VenueEmail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VenueMobile" HeaderText="VenueMobile" SortExpression="VenueMobile" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VenueContactPerson" HeaderText="VenueContactPerson" SortExpression="VenueContactPerson" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AddtionalName" HeaderText="AddtionalName" SortExpression="AddtionalName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AddtionalMobile" HeaderText="AddtionalMobile" SortExpression="AddtionalMobile" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VenueVendorEmail" HeaderText="VenueVendorEmail" SortExpression="VenueVendorEmail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="day" HeaderText="day" SortExpression="day" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="property" HeaderText="property" SortExpression="property" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="brandname" HeaderText="brandname" SortExpression="brandname" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="starttime" HeaderText="starttime" SortExpression="starttime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="endtime" HeaderText="endtime" SortExpression="endtime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="hrs" HeaderText="hrs" SortExpression="hrs" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="program" HeaderText="program" SortExpression="program" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:erp1ConnectionString %>">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:erp1ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="show_csuv1" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lbllgintype" Name="logintype" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblname" Name="name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

my cs page

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {



         if (com == "Admin")
        {
            lbllgintype.Text = com;
            lblname.Text = com1;
            sqlq = "";
            sqlq = "select id,comname from companydetails order by comname";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            //rldlstbrand.Items.Add("<-Select->");
            //ddllocation.Items.Add("<-Select->");
            rldlstcomname.DataSource = dt;
            //rldlstcomname.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns["comname"]);
            //rldlstcomname.DataValueField = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns["id"]);
            //rldlstcomname.DataBind();
            //rldlstcomname.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }

        //else if (com == "Admin")
        //{
        //    lbllgintype.Text = com;
        //    lblname.Text = com1;
        //    sqlq = "";
        //    sqlq = "select id,comname from companydetails order by comname";
        //    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
        //    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //    da.Fill(dt);
        //    rldlstbrand.Items.Add("<-Select->");
        //    ddllocation.Items.Add("<-Select->");    
        //    rldlstcomname.DataSource = dt;
        //    rldlstcomname.DataTextField = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns["comname"]);
        //    rldlstcomname.DataValueField = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns["id"]);
        //    rldlstcomname.DataBind();
        //    rldlstcomname.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");
        //}

        else if (com == "Partner Manager")
            {
                lbllgintype.Text = com;
                lblname.Text = com1;
                sqlq = "";
                sqlq = "exec AllotRPM '" + com1 + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                rldlstcomname.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                rldlstbrand.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                ddllocation.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    rldlstcomname.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }
            }
            else if (com == "Assistant Partner Manager")
            {
                lbllgintype.Text = com;
                lblname.Text = com1;

                sqlq = "";
                sqlq = "exec erprakesh.CallAPM '" + com1 + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                rldlstcomname.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                rldlstbrand.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                ddllocation.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    rldlstcomname.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

                }


            }



            else if (com == "Company")
            {
                lbllgintype.Text = com;
                lblname.Text = com1;


                sqlq = "";
                sqlq = "select comname from companydetails where comid='" + com1 + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlq, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                rldlstcomname.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                rldlstbrand.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                ddllocation.Items.Add("<-Select->");
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    rldlstcomname.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

                }

            }

        }




    }
```

}

my sql storedprocedure

```
alter proc [dbo].[show_csuv1]            
(            
@logintype varchar(50),            
@name nvarchar(100)            
)            
as                  
begin            

if(@logintype='admin')            
 begin             
  select       
  id,      
  Zone,      
  Location,      
  VenueName,      
  Venue,      
  VenueEmail,      
  VenueMobile,                  
  VenueContactPerson,      
  AddtionalName,      
  AddtionalMobile,      
  VenueVendorEmail,                  
  VenueVendorEmail,      
  VenueVendorEmail,                  
  convert(varchar(10),date,105) as[date],      
  day,      
  property,      
  brandname,      
  starttime,      
  endtime,      
  hrs,      
  program                  
  from CompanySonVinUnitVenue              
  where status='0'              
  order by id desc            
 end             
else if(@logintype='Partner Manager')            
  begin            
  Declare @emp varchar(100)            
  set @emp=(select empname from trainerdetails where trid=@name)            
  select id,Zone,Location,VenueName,Venue,VenueEmail,VenueMobile,                  
  VenueContactPerson,AddtionalName,AddtionalMobile,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  VenueVendorEmail,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  convert(varchar(10),date,105) as[date],day,property,brandname,starttime,endtime,hrs,program                  
  from CompanySonVinUnitVenue              
  where status='0' and property in(select id from companydetails where pm=@emp)          
 end      
else if(@logintype='Assistant Partner Manager')       
  begin            
  Declare @apm varchar(100)            
  set @apm=(select empname from trainerdetails where trid=@name)            
  select id,Zone,Location,VenueName,Venue,VenueEmail,VenueMobile,                  
  VenueContactPerson,AddtionalName,AddtionalMobile,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  VenueVendorEmail,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  convert(varchar(10),date,105) as[date],day,property,brandname,starttime,endtime,hrs,program                  
  from CompanySonVinUnitVenue      
  where status='0' and property in(select id from companydetails where apm=@apm)          
 end            

else if(@logintype='Company')          
 begin          
  Declare @com1 varchar(100)            
  set @com1 =(select id from companydetails where comid=@name)      
  select id,Zone,Location,VenueName,Venue,VenueEmail,VenueMobile,                  
  VenueContactPerson,AddtionalName,AddtionalMobile,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  VenueVendorEmail,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  convert(varchar(10),date,105) as[date],day,property,brandname,starttime,endtime,hrs,program                  
  from CompanySonVinUnitVenue              
  where status='0' and property =@com1      
 end  
else if(@logintype='Zonal Partner Manager')
begin
declare @zone1 varchar(100)            
  set @zone1 =(select zone from zonerpm where trainer=@name)      
  select id,Zone,Location,VenueName,Venue,VenueEmail,VenueMobile,                  
  VenueContactPerson,AddtionalName,AddtionalMobile,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  VenueVendorEmail,VenueVendorEmail,                  
  convert(varchar(10),date,105) as[date],day,property,brandname,starttime,endtime,hrs,program                  
  from CompanySonVinUnitVenue              
  where status='0' and zone = @zone1  
 end


end
```

I don't have access to other table but i know there is something wrong with my  visual studio coding and not with sql

please help I am on live project

Comment: In the C# code there is no detection for 'Zonal Partner Manager' only 'Admin', 'Partner Manager', 'Assistant Partner Manager' and 'Company'. This is why nothing is loading.

Comment: Check it > http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Comment: @BarryO'Kane it's working now i'm not getting the name from sessions properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are not binding data directly to you gridview using dataset in zonal div?

Eg.

```
rldlstcomname.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
rldlstcomname.DataBind();
```

Comment: there was a problem with me sessions :)